# I am getting this error "The multi-part identifier "DCOT.Loyalty" could not be bound."

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I was writing this code for setting loyalty and acquisition column to 0 or 1. I get an error:

> The multi-part identifier "DCOT.Loyalty" could not be bound

What am I doing here wrong? It seems to me some issue with joins.. can someone correct this for me?

```
DECLARE @CustomerSKID int
SET @CustomerSKID = (SELECT COUNT(CustomerSKID) 
                    FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor)

WHILE (@CustomerSKID) > 1
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Mintable1') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Mintable1
    END

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Mintable2') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Mintable2
    END

    SELECT 
        CustomerSKID, MIN(PurchaseDate) AS MinPDate 
    INTO 
        #Mintable1 
    FROM 
        Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor 
    WHERE 
        ManufacturerName = 'Mahindra' 
    GROUP BY
        CustomerSKID
                        
    SELECT CustomerSKID 
    INTO #Mintable2 
    FROM #Mintable1 
    WHERE MinPDate IS NOT NULL

    UPDATE Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor
    SET DCOT.Loyalty = 1
    FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor DCOT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Mintable2 AS M2 ON DCOT.CustomerSKID = M2.CustomerSKID
                                     AND DCOT.ManufacturerName = 'Mahindra'

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Mintable3') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Mintable3
    END

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Mintable4') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Mintable4
    END

    SELECT CustomerSKID, MAX(PurchaseDate) AS MaxPDate 
    INTO #Mintable3 
    FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor 
    WHERE ManufacturerName = 'Mahindra' 
    GROUP BY CustomerSKID
                        
    SELECT CustomerSKID 
    INTO #Mintable4 
    FROM #Mintable3 
    WHERE MaxPDate IS NOT NULL

    UPDATE Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor
    SET DCOT.Acquisition = 1
    FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor DCOT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Mintable2 AS M2 ON DCOT.CustomerSKID = M2.CustomerSKID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Mintable4 AS M4 ON DCOT.CustomerSKID = M4.CustomerSKID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Mintable3 AS M3 ON DCOT.CustomerSKID = M3.CustomerSKID
                                     AND DCOT.ManufacturerName = 'Mahindra'
                                     AND DCOT.PurchaseDate = M3.MaxPDate

    UPDATE Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor
    SET DCOT.Acquisition = 0
    FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor DCOT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Mintable1 AS M1 ON DCOT.CustomerSKID = M1.CustomerSKID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Mintable4 AS M4 ON DCOT.CustomerSKID = M4.CustomerSKID 
                                     AND DCOT.ManufacturerName != 'Mahindra'
                                     AND DCOT.PurchaseDate = M1.MinPDate
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` should reference your alias like `UPDATE DCOT`, or you can remove the alias from the set like `SET Loyalty = 1`.

With the mismatch, you're asking SQL to update a table named `Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor` and also telling SQL to use `DCOT` instead of that name.

Answer (score 0):

Correct table alias usage in SQL Server is

```
UPDATE DCOT
SET DCOT.Loyalty = 1
FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor DCOT
..
```

The table alias assigned to `Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor` in the FROM clause is specified as the target object in the UPDATE clause.

You can omitt a table alias in SET clause as well

```
UPDATE DCOT
SET Loyalty = 1
FROM Dim.DimCustomerOwnedTractor DCOT
..
```